# Howto add sourcepath to a maven-tycho build with m2e-plugin?

Tags: maven, classpath, m2e, tycho

I am building an Eclipse Application with maven tycho.
I package the project as an `eclipse-plugin`
When I do a Maven->Update my project's classpath gets destroyed, the src folders disapear.

How can I add custom source folders to my build?

[image]

Comment: Tycho takes source paths etc from build.properties. So you need to configure that using `src/main/java` as sourcepath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by `blackbuild` the source must be defined in `build.properties`

The syntax is the following:

```
source.. = src/main/java/,\
            src/test/java/,\
            src/prototype/java/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               src/
jars.compile.order = .
```